# Multiple DbContexts in abp.io project templates

Tags: ef-core-2.1, abp

There seems to be a separate DbContext in the Host project as well as a DbContext in the EntityFrameworkCore project in abp.io project templates (at the time of writing). I was wondering what the intended purpose is for these DbContexts? If I want to create a monolithic application with a single database, which DbContext should I use?

Comment: May you link to the db context you are talking about ? https://github.com/abpframework/abp/tree/master/templates . There is a large number of them https://github.com/abpframework/abp/search?q=DbContext&unscoped_q=DbContext

Comment: @JJJ I'm changing this back to have the abp tag only, since a new question came on that tag and the site abp.io links to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abp

Comment: We downloaded ASP.NET Core API Module (without UI). There are two DbContext for API. One of them is under Host project and another one is under EntityFrameworkCore project. @DragandDrop

Comment: In this template there is at least 4 '*dbContext.cs', not factory or configuration nor interface. That's why I asked clarification and exact path. 
Host should be the adp table  with Log and things when application db context is about your appliction table.